# What are the costs of multiple cross-contract calls in one contract call stack to callees with the same code?

Tags: smart-contract

As far as I know, contract calls are expensive because the called contract code must be loaded.

1. What if I make 2 cross-contract calls in one function to the same smart contract? Is the contract code loaded two times?
2. What if I make 2 cross-contract calls in one function to the two different smart contracts that share the same code_hash? For example, I call two different PSP22s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only really expensive part is loading the contract code because its size usually dominates every other storage access.

The costs of loading a contract code consists of two parts:

1. Pulling the contract from storage into the runtime
2. Delivering the contract code the the validator over the internet (only applies if pallet-contracts is deployed on a parachain).

Please note that the costs for **1** are **theoretically** reduced if you use the same code from the same `pallet-contracts::call` and the costs for **2** even when doing it within the same block.

**However**, we do not account for that right now. Due to the dynamic nature of weight tracking in `pallet-contracts` as opposed to simple pallets it would require additional work to make that happen: We would need to track which codes were accessed and then reduce the costs if they are loaded a second time. It is possible but it is just not happening right now.

Since we currently have no way to account for the costs of **2** we simulate it with [`ContractAccessWeight`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/97ae6be11b0132224a05634c508417f048894670/frame/contracts/src/lib.rs#L331-L350). We could reduce these costs if it happens in the same `pallet-contracts:call` in the same way as mentioned above. Tracking it per block is not in the cards right now.

Comment: " It is possible but it is just not happening right now." So basically in both case 1 & 2, 2 wasm blob are loaded from storage + delivered to network ?
It was sure for 2. as a call to 300 flipper with same code hash increase the PoV size a lot but was not sure for 1. case

Comment: No. In case 1: Loaded from cache. In case 2: Only included once in the PoV. However, we don't track this and hence the costs are still incurred even though the work does not occur.